# Android Button remains pressed when changing drawable

Tags: android, user-interface, android-drawable

I want to create a button which gets red on first press and gets back to normal gray on second (and do some action like delete a file). This is meant as a way to confirm that the user really wants to start the delete action.

To do this I change the background drawable to a LayerDrawable with an additional ColorDrawable on top of default drawable. The alpha of the ColorDrawable is then set to 0 or 255 according to state.

Switching to red on first click works but on second click the button gets yellow as in the pressed state while it should go back to normal gray.

Demo code:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    boolean showRed;
    ColorDrawable cd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Delete");

        // Following two lines don't matter, focus isn't the problem
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        cd = new ColorDrawable(0xffff0000);
        cd.setAlpha(0);

        button.setBackgroundDrawable(new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] {
                button.getBackground(), cd}));

        setContentView(button);


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showRed = !showRed;

                if (showRed)
                    cd.setAlpha(255);
                else
                    cd.setAlpha(0);

                // Following line doesn't matter
                button.setSelected(false);

                button.getBackground().invalidateSelf();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found the answer myself: Each Drawable references a Callback object which is informed if redrawing is needed. If the drawable is assigned to a View, this View is the Callback, if it is part of a compound drawable (like a LayerDrawable) this compound is the Callback.

The code line

```
    button.setBackgroundDrawable(new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] {
            button.getBackground(), cd}));
```

now did first place the button's default drawable into the LayerDrawable (so the Callback of the default background was set to the LayerDrawable). And then replaced the default background of the button by the newly created Drawable. When this happens, the Callback of the previous Drawable is set to null.

In the end the default background had no Callback to inform about the necessary redraw after a state change and remained (visually) in the wrong state.

The right way to do the above is:

```
    Drawable oldBg = button.getBackground();
    button.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    button.setBackgroundDrawable(new LayerDrawable(
            new Drawable[] {oldBg, cd}));
```

To first "disconnect" the default background and then create and set the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve can be easily done by using **toggle button** instead of normal button and giving it the background.

Toggle Button can handle your first click and second click problem as they are meant to switch.

What i am saying is use a toggle switch instead of normal button then according to your situation you can do two things :

1.> Assign the toggle button background to a selector xml file which would handle the color for different states (pressed , focussed , default etc). For the states check the docs on developer site.

2.> you can give the background a default color then what you can do is change the color for toggle checked and unchecked functions.

The only reason i suggested toggle button is that it is easy to handle first click and second click options.

Also, as soon as you change the toggle button background to any color or drawable from default it no more appears like a switch. You can also remove the on and off written by keeping the textOn and textOff attributes to blank

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="ToggleButton"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff="" />
```

Comment: I don't want to make it look like a toggle button (because it doesn't switch something on and off) so I would somehow need to make it look like an ordinary button by taking the drawable resources of the normal button. As these resources may vary between different Android versions (and different device manufacturers) and not even their names seem to be standardized this would be complicated (maybe I'm overlooking something)

Comment: and create 9 patch images for button background

Comment: My idea was that the button should look exactly like a regular button at least as long as it isn't red. Your suggestions (if I understand correctly) would mean to copy or reference drawable resources of the Android system which may change content or even name over time or between manufacturers so the special button wouldn't look regular anymore

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a selector for the purpose and place your selector in drawable folder.
This is suppose your button_state.xml in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
     android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
     android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

Then in your button you can add this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10px"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state" />
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly this would only use custom drawables for pressed or focused state. But I need actually a new state ("action_requested" or so).